# How to remove header phone number

Tags: layout, magento-1, template, theme, configuration

**I would like to change or remove the phone number on top right of this Magento site.**

Please can someone assist me. I have tried every where in the admin section to find it but couldn't find where to remove it.
Thanks in advance  guys.

Comment: Thanks all for the information. I tried and check through the path you gave me, I couldn't find the number to change. What i want to do is to replace the number to the correct number NOT to clear it as I would like to replace it with new one. What can i do again? –

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by ProxiBlue it is theme specific still I suggest you can check the following setting in backend

```
system > configuration > General > Store Information > Store Contact Telephone
```

If there is data provided remove it and try.

**Edit**

If you cant find it I suggest you open theme hint from the backend (Make sure you select the particular website scope to enable this option).

```
system > configuration > Developer > Debug > Template Path Hints
```

In frontend which file.phtml is called and check where the data is coming.

If you are non technical then copy paste the file.phtml code in your questuon probably then any one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This will be theme specific.

Enable template hints in admin. Clear cache. This will show you template that is outputting the value.  You can then view the template and from that determine where it gets the data from. Or maybe it is hard coded in template. Or come from a static block.

Answer (score 0):

I think the phone number is written in the file.

Go to the file : `app/design/frontend/default/theme505/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml`

if the file is not on this location then

Go to the file : `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalogsearch/form.mini.phtml`

Comment: It worked. I have changed it. Thanks so much Ashish Jagnani. I appreciate a lot.

Comment: @Emmanuel, If my answer helps you then mark as accepted. So other user can take benefit from this who has same issue like this.